# Rails + Materialize campo Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

Diplomatas, tenho o seguinte problema:

```
  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.label :kind_id %>
    <%= collection_select(:contact, :kind_id, @kind_options_for_select, :id, :description, class: 'input-field') %>
  </div>
```

Estou tentando aplicar a classe do select do materialize no rails, porém não está funcionando. Não mostra nada, apesar que tem dados.

[SOLUÇÃO PORÉM NÃO VEJO COMO A CORRETA]

```
  <div class="input-field">
    <%= collection_select(:contact, :kind_id, @kind_options_for_select, :id, :description, { prompt: "Choose a Kind" }, { class: 'browser-default' }) %>
  </div>
```

Essa class: 'browser-default' ela aplica um efeito que não seria igual do form padrão, mas aparece a combo com os dados.

Comment: Tem como mostrar o resultado disso? e o HTML gerado?

Comment: Altere sua resposta para o campo de respostas, e não no de perguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Este é o método com os parâmetros que devem ser passados:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Você está usando desta forma:

```
collection_select(:contact, :kind_id, @kind_options_for_select, :id, :description, class: 'input-field')
```

O argumento `class: 'input-field'` está sendo passado para `options`, mas deve ser passado para `html_options`. Então, você tem que passar um `hash` vazio para options para poder passar os parâmetros de `html_options`.

```
collection_select(:contact, :kind_id, @kind_options_for_select, :id, :description, {}, { class: 'input-field' })
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema não está relacionado com e Rails, mas sim com o materialize, de acordo com a própria documentação do select:

> Você deve inicializar o elemento select como mostrado abaixo. Além disso, você vai precisar de uma chamada separada para quaisquer elementos select gerados dinamicamente pela sua página.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });
```

Ou seja, toda vez que você criar ou alterar seu select dinâmicamente deve inicializa-lo.